# Maximal ideals of $k[x_1,\cdots,x_n]$ and degrees of field extensions

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, field-theory

For the past couple of days i had been working on an interesting homework problem, my interpretation of which is as follows:

Let $m$ be a maximal ideal of $k[x_1,\cdots,x_n]$. Let $m_i = m \cap k[x_i], i=1,\cdots,n$.
Then show that $m$ is the unique pre-image of $m_1,\cdots,m_n$, under the map
$\operatorname{Specm} k[x_1,\cdots,x_n] \rightarrow \prod_i \operatorname{Specm} k[x_i]$ given by $m \mapsto (m_i)_i$, if and only if 
$\left[k[x_1,\cdots,x_n]/m:k\right] = \prod_i \left[k[x_i]/m_i :k\right]$.

Related to this problem are the two questions of mine:
[Intersecting maximal ideals of $k[x_1,\dots,x_n]$ with $k[x_i]$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/211326/intersecting-maximal-ideals-of-kx-1-cdots-x-n-with-kx-i) and [Conditions for the degree of field extension reaches its upper bound](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/212235/conditions-for-the-degree-of-field-extension-reaches-its-upper-bound?lq=1).

PS: My homework is submitted, please feel free to attack to the problem :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There exists the following counter-example for your assertion.

Suppose $char(k) = p > 0$.
Let $\bar k$ be an algebraic closure.
Let $a \in k$.
Suppose $x^p - a$ is irreducible in $k[x]$.
Let $m_1 = (x_1^p - a)$, $m_2 = (x_2^p - a)$.
$x^p - a$ has a unique root $\alpha$ in $\bar k$.
Hence there exists unique maximal ideal $m$ of $k[x_1, x_2]$ such that $m_i = m \cap k[x_i]$ fo $i = 1, 2$.
Since $[k(\alpha) : k] = p$, $[k[x_1, x_2]/m : k] = p$ and $[k[x_i]/m_i: k] = p$ for $i = 1, 2$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am currently studying it. I think there is a typo: "$x^p-\alpha$ has a unique root $\alpha$ in $\bar{k}$".

Comment: @Manos It's not typo. It is true that $x^p - a$ has a unique root in $\bar k$. so does $x_1^p - a$ or $x_2^p - a$.

Comment: I agree that $x^p-\alpha$ has a unique root, but is this root equal to $\alpha$? In other words, why do we have that $\alpha^p=\alpha$? That is my point.

Comment: @Manos I did not write $x^p - \alpha$. I wrote $x^p - a$.

Comment: I understand. In your argument, is it true that $x_1 = x_2 \, \, (mod \, \,  m)?$

Comment: @Manos Yes. There exists a unique homomorphism $f\colon k[x_1, x_2] \rightarrow \bar k$ such that $f(x_1) = \alpha$ and $f(x_2) = \alpha$. $m = Ker(f)$. Since $f(x_1 - x_2) = 0$, $x_1 \equiv x_2$ (mod $m$).

Comment: Excellent as always :) Thanks.